# Error while using jquery with django to POST

Tags: jquery, django

I used a jquery dialog box in one of my templates in django as a confirmation to a delete operation but the problem is when i post data to the view i got the " `invalid regular expression flag d`" when debugging html code and the problem is in this line :

```
url : /certificates/delete/
```

Here is my code :

template :

```
function openDialog(id){

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
          resizable: true,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Delete This Entry": function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                    url: {% url delete_id %},
                    data: {'id': id},
                    success: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                    }
                });
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });
    }
```

Views :

```
def delete_id(request):
     id = request.POST.get('id', None)
```

URL:

```
url(r'^delete/', views.delete_id,name='delete_id')
```

Comment: In the method you have 'id' as an argument, but in the url() no where I can see the 'id' argument.

Comment: it's a number so (\d+) do the work

Comment: Of course its a number, but without giving a name to it how it will map.

Comment: Your views.py is inside which app? Is it inside certificates app !

Comment: I modified it it's in entries app

Comment: I have modified my answer, can you pls try putting the new modification.

Comment: no need to specify the app as the views are in the application its self i'm not importing them

Comment: `url: /entries/delete/`, the value has to be in quotes or javascript treats it as a regex, `url: "/entries/delete/"`

Comment: it was that ! thank you but now i got another error lol please check my update

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to generate the delete url on the server side, but the ID is handled in client side.

Instead of having the "id" parameter part of the url, consider moving it to POST data:

```
def delete_id(request):
     id = request.POST.get("id", None)
     if id is not None:
         print 'delete'
```

---

```
url(r'^delete/', views.delete_id,name='delete_id')
```

Applying These changes will make your code work.

Comment: This is another question that has a lot of answers already.. search for it "django post ajax csrf". its not related at all to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to correct your url declaration like this:

```
url(r'^delete/', entries.views.delete_id,name='delete_id')
```

Inside your view write this

```
id = request.POST.get('id', None)
```

The error message also indicates that it is not able to map the argument.

Comment: I have modified my answer, please check now.